# How to display the similarity between classes?

Tags: matlab, classification, correlation, pca

I have handwritten samples from two writers. I am using a feature extractor to extract features from both.

I want to display the similarity between the classes. As to show how identical both are and how difficult it can be for a classifier to classify them correctly.

I have read papers that use PCA to demonstrate this. I tried with PCA but I dont think I'm implementing this correctly. I'm using this to display the similarity.

```
[COEFF,SCORE] = princomp(features_extracted);
plot(COEFF,'.')
```

But for every class and every sample I get exactly the same plot. I mean they should be similar not exactly the same. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: How many features do you have from each class? With PCA you transform the feature space into a new 'pca' space. What you are plotting is the coefficients used to transform the features to the new feature space, not the transformed features. Remember that PCA is an unsupervised method that just finds the vector in the data with the most variance, nothing more. This may indicate seperability, but it may not. To get the actual transformed features, use `transformed = features_extracted * COEFF`.

Comment: Then you can plot the relationship between the first two features as `scatter(transformed(:, 1), transformed(:  2))`. Also, remember that your data in `features_extracted` should be Gaussian distributed, with zero-mean, unit-variance (if it is not perfectly Gaussian is ok, but it *must* be zero-mean, unit-variance for each feature individually).

Comment: Finally, make sure that `features_extracted` is formatted so that each row is an observation, and each column is a feature.

Comment: However, bear in mind that `PCA` in not really a suitable tool when you have only two samples.

Comment: Although maybe I have misinterpreted your data - if you can give us some more details would be helpful. You clearly have two classes, but how many samples per class, and how many features per sample?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response @zelanix. I have more than 50 classes. About 10 samples per class and am using a feature extractor that produces over 4000 features per sample. I used two classes in my question as I assumed that would be enough to show similarity between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will struggle to show anything significant with only 10 samples per class, and over 4000 features.

Nevertheless, the following code will calculate PCA and show the relationship between the first two principal components (the components that contain 'most' variance).

```
% Truly indistinguishable data
dummy_data = randn(20, 4000);

% Uncomment this to make the data distinguishable
%dummy_data(1:10, :) = dummy_data(1:10, :) - 0.5;

% Normalise the data - this isn't technically required for the dummy data
% above, but is included for completeness.
dummy_data_normalised = dummy_data;
for f = 1:size(a, 2)
    dummy_data_normalised(:, f) = dummy_data_normalised(:, f) - nanmean(dummy_data_normalised(:, f));
    dummy_data_normalised(:, f) = dummy_data_normalised(:, f) / nanstd(dummy_data_normalised(:, f));
end

% Generate vector of 10 0's and 10 1's
class_labels = reshape(repmat([0 1], 10, 1), 20, 1);

% Perform PCA
pca_coeffs = pca(dummy_data_normalised);

% Calculate transformed data
dummy_data_pca = dummy_data_normalised * pca_coeffs;

figure;
hold on;

for class = unique(class_labels)'
    % Plot first two components of first class
    scatter(dummy_data_pca(class_labels == class, 1), dummy_data_pca(class_labels == class, 2), 'filled')
end

legend(strcat({'Class '},int2str(unique(class_labels)))')
```

For indistinguishable data, this will show a scatter plot similar to the following:

[image]

Clearly it is not possible to draw a separation boundary between the two classes.

If you uncomment the fifth line to make the data distinguishable, then the plot will instead come out as follows:

[image]

However, to repeat what I wrote in my comment, PCA *does not* necessarily find the components that give the best separation. It is an unsupervised method and only finds the components with the largest variance. In some applications, this is also the components that give good separation. With only 10 samples per class, you will not be able to demonstrate anything statistically significant. Also have a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28909/pca-when-the-dimensionality-is-greater-than-the-number-of-samples) for more details on PCA and the number of samples per class.

**EDIT:** This also extends naturally to having more classes:

```
numer_of_classes = 10;
samples_per_class = 20;

% Truly indistinguishable data
dummy_data = randn(numer_of_classes * samples_per_class, 4000);

% Make the data distinguishable
for i = 1:numer_of_classes
    ixd = (((i - 1) * samples_per_class) + 1):(i * samples_per_class);
    dummy_data(ixd, :) = dummy_data(ixd, :) - (0.5 * (i - 1));
end

% Normalise the data
dummy_data_normalised = dummy_data;
for f = 1:size(a, 2)
    dummy_data_normalised(:, f) = dummy_data_normalised(:, f) - nanmean(dummy_data_normalised(:, f));
    dummy_data_normalised(:, f) = dummy_data_normalised(:, f) / nanstd(dummy_data_normalised(:, f));
end

% Generate vector of classes (1 to numer_of_classes)
class_labels = reshape(repmat(1:numer_of_classes, samples_per_class, 1), numer_of_classes * samples_per_class, 1);

% Perform PCA
pca_coeffs = pca(dummy_data_normalised);

% Calculate transformed data
dummy_data_pca = dummy_data_normalised * pca_coeffs;

figure;
hold on;

for class = unique(class_labels)'
    % Plot first two components of first class
    scatter(dummy_data_pca(class_labels == class, 1), dummy_data_pca(class_labels == class, 2), 'filled')
end

legend(strcat({'Class '},int2str(unique(class_labels)))')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed response.